# User page and Recent (mail icon) page

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, profile-page

It might just be me, but I sometimes find the breakout of information between the main User page, and the "Recent" page (mail icon) a little confusing.  I can never remember which page to go to to check the status on a recent question or answer.

I was thinking it might make sense if these two pages were combined into a single view, where you can see the status of everything (lists of activities, reputation updates, reputation chart, etc.), maybe in a tabbed format, or something like that.  For example, on one tab, you might see your rep chart, along with a list of recent changes, possibly combined somehow with the list of total reputation earned for a particular item in the past period of time.

If these were combined, the mail icon could still be highlighted for recent activity, but it would just take you into the all-encompassing User view, and possibly highlight the areas that have recently changed.

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea, just have the `Recent Activity` page on the top of the `User Profile` page.

Comment: Or even just a link between the two would be a nice step in the right direction.

Comment: I agree. I had to look at this question before I found out how to get to my recent activity page from my user page. The mail icon looks like a status indicator, not a link.